# Кнопки шириной на весь экран

Tags: android, xml

Как сделать кнопку, чтобы она была шириной на весь экран(то есть масштабируемая).

Comment: layout_width:"match_parent" не подходит?

Comment: Нет, растягивает его немного, но не на всю ширину экрана.

Comment: Может родительский слой имеет padding, который и не даёт растянуть по краям

Comment: покажите код своего layout'a

Comment: закинул код в тему

Comment: Вы назначили отступы, и удивляетесь, почему же есть отступы...

Comment: Уточните вопрос - у вас на каждом разрешении экрана сейчас кнопки должны занимать всю ширину экрана, с отступами с левой и с правой стороны по 72dp, так что именно не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Назначить у нее и всех ее предков `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: нет, не помогает.

Comment: Уберите android:layout_marginRight="72dp" или сделайте его 0dp